How to create a SIRI shortcut programmatically that triggers a phone call with the Phone app?
I'm aware that we can create shortcuts programmatically to our own app with the INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController. I did that, it works, that's fine.
But I would like now to automate the creation of a SIRI shortcut to the Phone app that will trigger a phone call to a given number. Is that possible?
I don't think it is but I'm asking anyway...
Appart from the INUIAddVoiceShortcutViewController, the closest thing I've been able to do is just to open the Shortcut creation form from my app with UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"shortcuts://create-shortcut"))... If I could at least pass params to pre-fill the form, that would be almost fine...

This feels like a giant security issue if this were allowed.

If you are going to "call the OS" (haha) via a URL, try using tel:
The Apple documentation is old, with few revisions, ATM, it is still in the "archive" section ->
Phone Links
The latest RFC was from 2004 ->
The tel URI for Telephone Numbers, with a revision later.
I should caution that the real work is not calling access, but phone number formatting. Coders (and users) often overestimate how the phone module will react to the dialing sequence they provide.
NOTE:
This scheme distinct from telnet:, but they hail from the same era.

Hi ! Thank you for your reply but I do not see how this would help me in creating a SIRI shortcut...

Lets see if someone else can explain that part.. :)
